# Django CBV : post() and form_valid() methods

Tags: django

I would like to use `post()` and `form_valid()` methods in order to fill my form, submit data and make some processes with data.

My class looks like this :

```
class HomeView(CreateView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'app/index.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        email = request.POST['email']
        country_id = request.POST['country']
        country = Country.objects.get(id=country_id)

        for checkbox in request.POST.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
            document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
            token = self.gen_token(email, document.edqm_id)
            Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, pub_id=checkbox, token=token,
                                    expiration_date=now + timedelta(minutes=10))

            if not form.is_valid():
                print('form invalid')
                continue

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I would like to add `form_valid()` method in order to not override my `post()` method.

I tried something like this :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    email = request.POST['email']
    country_id = request.POST['country']
    country = Country.objects.get(id=country_id)
    print("I'm in post method")

    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app-home'))

def form_valid(self, form):

    print("I'm in form_valid method")

    for checkbox in self.request.POST.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
        document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
        token = self.gen_token(self.email, document.edqm_id)
        Download.objects.create(email=self.email, country=self.country, pub_id=checkbox, token=token,
                                expiration_date=now + timedelta(minutes=10))

        self.send_email(self.email, document.upload, document.publication.title, document.edqm_id, token)

    return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

But I don't overcome to make work my class, especially with this issue : `'HomeView' object has no attribute 'email'`

I think I have a misunderstanding with that.

***Edit :***

With cleaned_data :

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    country = form.cleaned_data['country']

    for checkbox in self.request.POST.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
        document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
        token = self.gen_token(email, document.edqm_id)
        Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, pub_id=checkbox, token=token,
                                expiration_date=now + timedelta(minutes=10))

        self.send_email(email, document.upload, document.publication.title, document.edqm_id, token)

    return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

It seems to work but I am not sure about the syntax ?

Comment: `email` is not an attr of the view, note your are doing `self.email` at `self.send_email`. You can access to all data in the form through  `form.cleaned_data` after doing `form.is_valid()`. For more detail see this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#field-data

Comment: @trinchet Iedited my question and it seems to work. I'm just not sure with the syntax.

Comment: What you mean with syntax? Are you getting any syntax error?